# IE7/IE8 - not displaying background image

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I am designing a site that has a background image, that is simply repeated in the y axis.

```
#background {
  background: url("../image/bg.png") repeat-y  -43px 150px;
}
```

This works fine in FireFox and Safari, but not in IE7 or IE8.

I have even added stylesheets for these 2 browsers and changed the background to a color (which worked) rather than the image.

Is there any reason why this isn't working in these 2 browsers?

Thanks

Comment: just to know... what's the original height of your image `bg.png`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Does the background have any sizes? as it will need this... If it does and thats not working have you set your doctype in the page? IE Requires this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: I have not set dimensions on the background div. The doctype is `strict` does this need changing to `transitional`?

Comment: Try setting height:100%; width:100%; in css... let me know how you get on.

Comment: Well it seems that `-43px` wasn't enough and was actually hidden behind the div the background was sat behind. I changed it to -180px and could see the background image.

Answer (score 0):

use !important in background style like this for IE7 & IE8.

```
#background {
  background: url("../image/bg.png") repeat-y  -43px 150px !important;
}
```